# Locate source of Backbone.js event error that never hits non-library code

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools

Pretty sure that the error output below from the Chrome browser is due to an event being bound in Backbone.js to something that is not a function.

All I really need to know is the name of the even that got fired and I should be able to easily locate the source of the error. Normally I would set a break point, but the thread never touches any of the project code.

**What is a good way to use available tools to determine the fired event that led to this error?**

Thanks so much!

[image]

Comment: This is one of those errors that debugging sucks for; mostly because neither of those libraries are going to be the issue. What you should do, is remove specific .js files until the error no longer exists. Then go through the file that has the error and set break points until you find it.

Comment: one obvious point would be to not use the minified versions of jquery and backbone when trying to debug as that is nearly impossible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have `model: YourModel()` instead of `model: YourModel`

Comment: @CladiuHojda Which form is correct? Your answer is ambiguous

Comment: @jpaugh seriously? after 3 years no one found this ambiguous....you can find more info in [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model), you must pass the model class to your collection. PS: stop using Windows so much, it can hurt your clear thinking

Comment: @ClaudiuHojda My goal is to help [so] be a place with accurate, understandable information. I suggested that you edit it because someone new to Backbone might struggle to understand your post, since it relies on the OP's context to make sense. Is it bad to have a two line answer instead of a one line answer?